# change Decr_console/Incr_console to other key combination

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, console

I have just migrated to Debian 9.

It turns out that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> switches to another virtual console (`Decr_console`/`Incr_console`) which prevents me from using this key combination in emacs' orgmode.

How can I disable this Debian key binding?

Or maybe change `Decr_console`/`Incr_console` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>?

Comment: This question seems related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146060/how-to-disable-alt-arrow-switching-of-virtual-consoles